# Best way to construct a pandas.DataFrame composed of different chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running daily simulations in a batch: I do 365 simluations to get results for a full year.  After every run, I want to extract some arrays from the results and add them to a pandas.DataFrame for analysis later.

I have a rough model (doing an optimisation) and a more precise model for a post-simulation, so I can get the same variable from two sources. In case the post-simulation is done, the results may overwrite the optimization results.
To make it more complicated, the optimization model has a smaller output interval, depending on the discretisation settings, but the final analysis will happen on the larger interval of the post-simulation).

What is the best way to construct this DataFrame?

This was my first appraoch:

1. creation of an empty `DataFrame` `df` for the full year, with `DateRange` index with the larger post- simulation interval (=15 minutes)
2. do optimization for 1 day ==> create temporary `df_temp` with `DateRange` as index with smaller interval
3. downsample this `DataFrame` to 15 minutes as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling):
4. update `df` with `df_temp` (rows in `df` are still empty, except for the last row of the previous run, so I have to take `df_temp[1:]`)
5. do simulation for same day ==> create temporary `df_temp2` with interval = 15min
6. overwrite the corresponding rows in `df` with `df_temp2`

Which methods should I use in step 4) and 6)?  Or is there a better way from the start?
Thanks,
Roel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `DataFrame.combine_first` could be the way to go, but depending on the scale of the data, it might be more useful to have a method like "update" that just modified particular rows in an existing DataFrame. `combine_first` is more general and can cause the result to be of a different size than either of the inputs (because the indexes will get unioned together).

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/961

Comment: Yes, combine_first works fine indeed, as long as you call it from `df_temp`.  And I instantiate the empty DataFrame without index.   Thanks for your help.